# Why do I need a C++ redistributable for a specific IDE?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

When developing in C++, it is frequent for developers to use Visual Studio for Windows development. When setting up the VS IDE, Microsoft provides a set of C++ redistributable that are available for download in order to use Visual Studio. The C++ redistributeable contains `.dll` for standard librarires such as `<stdio>`. My question here is, why does Microsoft say on there website that these distributable are "for Visual Studio". What is preventing me for example, downloading the C++ redistributables and using a different IDE, let's suppose Geany and editing the source code elsewhere. All we need is the `.dll` of the standard libraries, once they're obtained we can edit our source code anywhere we desire?

Comment: The redistributable contains the code for the runtime libraries when linked as a DLL. They are not so much "for Visual Studio" as they are for the headers distributed with a particular version of the Microsoft compiler. If you want to edit your code elsewhere and use that compiler nothing is stopping you, but unless you are static linking everything you will still need the redistributable to run that compiled program.

Comment: Oh yeah you may also look into using https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows-c0514201-7fe6-95a3-b0a5-287930f3560c aka the Universal C Runtime.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/upgrade-your-code-to-the-universal-crt?view=msvc-160

Comment: The msvc compiler in VS2015 to 2019 are binary compatible with each other but not compatible with any other msvc version. Related: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160) They are also not generally compatible with mingw when it comes to c++ based binaries. If you stick to `c` only there is some compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing whatsoever to do with the IDE. It's about Microsoft's C++ compiler, which requires a redistributable for the run-time libraries when you use dynamic linking. And the redistributables are version-specific.

A different version of the C++ compiler toolchain is bundled with each new release of the Visual Studio IDE. Unfortunately, the Visual Studio version number is very different from the actual version of the C++ compiler. So, Microsoft has chosen to use the Visual Studio version to label the run-time redistributable, because this version number is much better known. A version number mapping table is maintained in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Internal_version_numbering) ("MSVC++ version" is the version number of Microsoft Visual C++, which is the build toolchain).

You can use any build toolchain you like with the IDE, including non-Microsoft tools, which would require their own run-time redistributables. Similarly, you could invoke Microsoft's build tools from another IDE, in which case, you'd still require Microsoft's redistributables.

Or, you could use static linking to integrate the run-time libraries directly into your executables, in which case you would not require the redistributable at all. But this has the notable downside that your application will not benefit from any security updates to the run-time libraries. You'll need to recompile and redeploy your executable to get those security updates.

Comment: Just to check my understanding here, are you saying that when we download the C++ redistributables we're downloading the compiled versions of the standard libraries that used compiler X to produce the .dlls. In our IDE we have to be using compiler X so that when our source code is compiled it can be linked to the .dll (redistributeable) we have downloaded? The key note here being, you compiler you're using in your IDE is the same compiler that was used to produce the .dll in your redistributeable.

Answer (score 0):

The redistributable packages are not really for the IDE. They are for the compiler. Various version of `cl` expect particular sets of library support.

So you can use any IDE if it calls the Microsoft `cl` compiler application and use the packages for that compiler.

Or you can do the opposite and avoid the packages by using mingw / mingw-w64 / MSYS2 which is GCC and other Unix tools compiled against the pre-installed Windows runtime libraries.

Comment: mingw-w64 binaries also have DLL dependencies, by default. In both cases it's possible to do monolithic static builds. If you don't do a static build then you have to deploy these DLLs with your mingw-w64 built executable

Comment: Just to check my understanding here, are you saying that when we download the C++ redistributables we're downloading the compiled versions of the standard libraries that used compiler X to produce the `.dlls`. In our IDE we have to be using compiler X so that when our source code is compiled it can be linked to the `.dll` (redistributeable) we have downloaded? The key note here being, you compiler you're using in your IDE is the same compiler that was used to produce the `.dll` in your redistributeable.

Comment: @Joe If you pick Visual Studio 17's C++ compiler then you need the DLL for 17. Otherwise it won't have support for the updated versions of C++ std::string and other things. I also tried to show how you can avoid the redist packages by using UCRT instead. Or mingw, but yes you have libraries there too, which I guess I always static-linked.